# Code using RcppArmadillo compiles when running R from terminal but not rstudio-server

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo, rstudio-server

I'm trying to get some c++ code to compile using sourceCpp and RcppArmadillo. I'm using R 3.3.3 on Ubuntu, Rcpp 0.12.10 and RcppArmadillo 0.7.800.2.0. The file, armatest.cpp, is totally stripped down.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace arma; 
using namespace Rcpp;

int one() {
  return 1;
}
```

When I attempt to compile this from within Rstudio server, I get the following compilation error:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("armatest.cpp", verbose = TRUE, rebuild=TRUE)

Generated extern "C" functions 
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>

Generated R functions 
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/tmp/Rtmp3oSZra/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.10/sourcecpp_47d41ae4918/sourceCpp_10.so')


rm(`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /tmp/Rtmp3oSZra/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.10/sourcecpp_47d41ae4918

/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_10.so' --preclean  'armatest.cpp'  
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG    -I"/home/amercer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/amercer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/home/amercer"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c armatest.cpp -o armatest.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_10.so armatest.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'sourceCpp_10.so' failed
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("armatest.cpp", verbose = TRUE, rebuild = TRUE) : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

However, when I run R from the command line (outside of Rstudio-server), and try again, it compiles just fine.

```
>Rcpp::sourceCpp("armatest.cpp", verbose = TRUE, rebuild=TRUE)

Generated extern "C" functions
--------------------------------------------------------


#include <Rcpp.h>

Generated R functions
-------------------------------------------------------

`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo` <- dyn.load('/tmp/RtmptRileh/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.10/sourcecpp_1966315b9edd0/sourceCpp_4.so')


rm(`.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo`)

Building shared library
--------------------------------------------------------

DIR: /tmp/RtmptRileh/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-0.12.10/sourcecpp_1966315b9edd0

/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_4.so' --preclean  'armatest.cpp'
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG    -I"/home/amercer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/amercer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/home/amercer"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c armatest.cpp -o armatest.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_4.so armatest.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
Warning message:
In Rcpp::sourceCpp("armatest.cpp", verbose = TRUE, rebuild = TRUE) :
  No Rcpp::export attributes or RCPP_MODULE declarations found in source
```

As far as I can tell, they are executing exactly the same commands with the same flags. What explains the difference? Rcpp on its own works just fine for me in Rstudio-server, so it's something about RcppAarmadillo specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Likely something local to your setup as it works fine here also from RStudio---but note that I did add an `// [[Rcpp::export]]` as well as an auto-executing example:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/armaQ.cpp")

> one()
[1] 1
>
```

Your example, minimally altered:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace arma; 
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int one() {
  return 1;
}

/*** R
one()
*/
```